# How to use core php library in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

. I want to implement this package in my laravel. Package link is below:-

```
https://github.com/joshdick/miniProxy/blob/master/miniProxy.php
```

Its working fine when i run using php file. But i don't knw how to implement this package file in laravel. This package contains only one file. Can anyone guide me or help me how to do this package functioning in laravel.

Comment: try to search a package in laravel with the same functionality instead of it

Comment: I have tried but no package found :(

Comment: if you knw any pacakage please share the link

Answer (score 1):

You can simply include this file in your class. Put it somewhere meaningful, like /vendor or /lib and `include` it in the class where you want to use it.

Some information on including external PHP files: https://laraveldaily.com/how-to-use-external-classes-and-php-files-in-laravel-controller/

Comment: laravel does not get in the way of using normal PHP functions, so this always works. of course you could always convert this script to a composer package and require it in your target application, but you'd most probably have to maintain it yourself, which does not give you any benefit over simply including the script directly.

Answer (score 1):

simply add it in your composer.json

Answer (score 0):

You can create a ServiceProvider like this in app/Providers :

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class HelperServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
    * Bootstrap the application services.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        foreach (glob(app_path().'/Helpers/*.php') as $filename) {
            require_once($filename);
        }
    }
}
```

In you config/app file, add this new serviceProvier

```
App\Providers\HelperServiceProvider::class,
```

Then create a folder /Helpers in /app folder (./app/Helpers) and put your file in this folder.
Now you can access all this folder functions from everywhere.

Comment: i have created the proxy.php file in app/Helpers/proxy.php and created the HelperServiceProvider in app/Providers and after that i am trying to access like this Localhost/Helpers/proxy.php its not working

Comment: Just call the function you need. no need to import anything. In a controller or model, try to call makeRequest function.

Comment: The serviceProvider loads all functions in helpers folder. they are available from anywhere in your project. You just have to call them

Comment: i want one url and  i want that file will work as core php  not as laravel